# Ejecutar Python en C++ | No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, c++, rutas

Estoy tratando de ejecutar código de python en c++. Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019 16.3.1. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hola mundo desde python')");
    Py_Finalize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Y me está surgiendo este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí en varios hilos que el problema puede estar en el path de python, pero de ser así no termino de entender como configurarlo. Estoy usando python 3.7 instalado con Anaconda. Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Se puede ejecutar Python scripts desde la consola? Si sí, tienes una instalación funcional. Tu programa debe enlazar con bibliotecas de Python de esta instalación, y debe ver variables de entorno (PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH etc) que apuntan a esta instalación. Si no, entonces tienes una instalación rota.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar. Copie el archivo python37.dll a la carpeta System32. No se que tan sano será eso pero me está funcionando ahora

Comment: Añadir cosas a System32 no es una buena idea... te morderá tarde o temprano.